# How to make key element match the schema when uploading parsed csv file to DyanmoDB using python

Tags: python, csv, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm Working out of AWS Cloud9 and I'm getting the following error, "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema".

I tried recreating a smaller table to figure it out. I created a table by with just 2 columns: 'Card_Number' (Number) and 'Details' (String).

I've tried throwing in something like this in the item[] section but it created a syntax error I was unable to resolve...

```
items = ['Card_Number':row.split{',')[0],
            'Detials':row.split{',')[1]]

import boto3
import csv

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-1')

def batch_write(table_name,rows):
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for row in rows:
        batch.put_item(Item=row)
return True

def read_csv(csv_file,list):

    rows = csv.DictReader(open('testTable1.csv'))

for row in rows:
    list.append(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':

table_name = 'testTable1'
file_name = 'testTable1.csv'
items= []

read_csv(file_name, items)
status = batch_write(table_name,items)

if(status):
    print('Data is saved')
else:
    print('Error while insterting data...')
```

I'd like to see the data show up in DynamoDB, I've been at this for weeks and have no prior experience. So, I could really use some help to hold on to my sanity.

Comment: How does you table key schema look like? What is in `row`? Also, the code above is not well formatted - you have a higher likelihood of getting help if you provide a well formatted and reproducible example.

Comment: row would include 2 values separated by commas.